# I am trying to use boost, C++ with templates, and factory pattern but can't seem to figure out the right syntax for it?

Tags: c++11, templates, boost, factory, instantiation

Here is the specifics:

1. Consider a simple constructor in a class with two input arguments, 
           `concreteclass(_1, _2)`.
2. I have a map for this instantiation, map `<string, concreteclassType>`.
3. Also, these classes work with different datatypes `concreteclass<double>(_1,_2)` is different from `concreteclass<int>(_1,_2)`.

Now that my problem is described above here is what I try to do using boost::factory pattern, classes defined in a string map and datatypes defined in an enum.

First, there is a simple way to demonstrate how boost factory pattern can be used with constructor arguments, the following nicely code works:

```
// Factory which takes two arguments
struct base {
    base(int alpha) : alpha(alpha) {}
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void print() const = 0;

    int alpha;
};

struct derived : public base {
    derived(int alpha, int beta) : base(alpha), beta(beta) {}
    void print() const override {
        std::cout << alpha << " " << beta << std::endl;
    }

    int beta;
};


void TestBoostFactoryWithTwoArgs()
{
    // Constructor factory with two input args
    {
        std::map<std::string, boost::function<base* (int&, int&)>> factories;
        factories["derived"] = boost::bind(boost::factory<derived*>(), _1, _2);
        int x = 42;
        int y = 51;
        std::unique_ptr<base> b{ factories.at("derived")(x,y) };
        b->print();
    }
    // Factory with two initialized inputs args - binding of values not at run time 
    {
        std::map<std::string, boost::function<base* ()>> factories;
        factories["derived"] = boost::bind(boost::factory<derived*>(), 42, 51);
        std::unique_ptr<base> b{ factories.at("derived")() };
        b->print();
    }
}
```

Now consider my code - SimpleClasses.h:

```
// Dummy base class - non template
class IBaseClass
{
public:

};

// Templatized Derived Base class
template <typename T>
class ConcreteClass : public IBaseClass
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<IBaseClass> m_leftArgument;
    std::shared_ptr<IBaseClass> m_leftArgument;
public:
    ConcreteClass(std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass>& leftArgument, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass>& rightArgument)
    {
        m_leftArgument = leftArgument;
        m_rightArgument = rightArgument;
    };

    virtual T DoSomething()
    {
        cout << "I did something in Concrete Base Class" << endl;
        return T();
    }; // This is the main reason for creating T

};

template <typename T>
class ConcreteClassA : ConcreteClass
{

};

template <typename T>
class ConcreteClassB : ConcreteClass
{

};

template <typename T>
class ConcreteClassC : ConcreteClass
{

};
```

Another File, ClassFactory.h :

```
#pragma once

#include "SimpleClasses.h"
#include <memory> 
#include <map>
#include <boost/functional/overloaded_function.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/factory.hpp>

using namespace std;

// Add More class Keys here
namespace MyClassesNamespace { // These are all string keys
    static const string CLASS_A = "specialclassA";
    static const string CLASS_B = "specialclassB";
    static const string CLASS_C = "specialclassC";
};

enum EMyDataTypes
{
    INT8,
    FLOAT8,
    FLOAT16,
};


// This type def we keep for non templatized base class constructor
typedef boost::function<IBaseClass*(std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass>&, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass>&)> IBaseClassConstructorFunc_factory;

// Dummy base factory - no template  
class UBaseClassTemplateFactory
{
public:
};

template<typename T>
class UClassFactoryTemplate : public UBaseClassTemplateFactory
{
private:
    static std::map<string, IBaseClassConstructorFunc_factory> ClassFactoryTemplateMap; // Unique Classes only


public:
    UClassFactoryTemplate();
    __forceinline static UClassFactoryTemplate*Get()
    {
        static UClassFactoryTemplate<T> SingletonInstance;
        return &SingletonInstance;
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass<T>> CreateClassTemplatized(string ClassString, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> LeftArgument, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> RightArgument);
};


// This type def we keep for non templatized base class
typedef boost::function<UBaseClassTemplateFactory*()> ClassFactoryTemplate_factory;


/* This is the instance class that resolves the classes as well as the concrete datatype to be used in UClassFactoryTemplate*/
class UClassFactory
{

private:
    UClassFactory();
    static std::map<EMyDataTypes, ClassFactoryTemplate_factory> ClassDataTypeTemplateFactoryMap;


public:

    __forceinline static UClassFactory *Get()
    {
        static UClassFactory SingletonInstance;
        return &SingletonInstance;
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> CreateConcreteClass(string ClassString, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> LeftVal, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> RightVal, EMyDataTypes someEnumVal = EMyDataTypes::INT8);

};
```

Finally, in ClassFactory.cpp

```
#include "ClassFactory.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

/*static, but non-const data members should be defined outside of the class definition
*and inside the namespace enclosing the class. The usual practice is to define it in
*the translation unit (*.cpp) because it is considered to be an implementation detail.
*Only static and const integral types can be declared and defined at the same time (inside class definition):*/

template<typename T>
std::map<string, IBaseClassConstructorFunc_factory> UClassFactoryTemplate<T>::ClassFactoryTemplateMap;
std::map<EMyDataTypes, ClassFactoryTemplate_factory> UClassFactory::ClassDataTypeTemplateFactoryMap;


template<typename T>
inline UClassFactoryTemplate<T>::UClassFactoryTemplate()
{
    ClassFactoryTemplateMap[MyClassesNamespace::CLASS_A] = boost::bind(boost::factory<ConcreteClassA<T>*>(), _1, _2);
    ClassFactoryTemplateMap[MyClassesNamespace::CLASS_B] = boost::bind(boost::factory<ConcreteClassB<T>*>(), _1, _2);
    ClassFactoryTemplateMap[MyClassesNamespace::CLASS_C] = boost::bind(boost::factory<ConcreteClassC<T>*>(), _1, _2);
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass<T>> UClassFactoryTemplate<T>::CreateClassTemplatized(string ClassString, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> LeftArgument, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> RightArgument)
{
    std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass<T>> someTemplatizedDataTypeInstance{ ClassFactoryTemplateMap.at(ClassString) (LeftArgument,RightArgument) };
    return someTemplatizedDataTypeInstance;
}

UClassFactory::UClassFactory()
{
    ClassDataTypeTemplateFactoryMap[EMyDataTypes::INT8] = boost::bind(boost::factory<UClassFactoryTemplate<int>*>());
    ClassDataTypeTemplateFactoryMap[EMyDataTypes::FLOAT8] = boost::bind(boost::factory<UClassFactoryTemplate<float>*>());
    ClassDataTypeTemplateFactoryMap[EMyDataTypes::FLOAT16] = boost::bind(boost::factory<UClassFactoryTemplate<double>*>());
}

std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> UClassFactory::CreateConcreteClass(string ClassString, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> LeftVal, std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> RightVal, EMyDataTypes someEnumVal)
{
    std::unique_ptr<UBaseClassTemplateFactory>  BaseOperatorTempFactory{ ClassDataTypeTemplateFactoryMap.at(someEnumVal) };
    return BaseOperatorTempFactory->Get()::CreateClassTemplatized(ClassString, LeftVal, RightVal);
}
```

The question now is, the above code does not even compile let alone run, it says abstract class cannot be instantiated for the templatized map. I just want the UClassFactory to return me correct instantiated class like A,B,C based on a string map with correct datatypes based on an enum. How do I achieve this combination? I wonder what is the correct syntax? Or is my approach inherently flawed? Or there is a nice way to instantiate classes with factory pattern and different datatypes? Please let me know any suggestions/ comments.

Thanks

Alam